# Java Recursive Method (Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 4 out of bounds for length 4)

Tags: java, recursion, methods

I'm trying to take an object array and print out the reverse using a recursive method but I'm getting the above listed error. Could someone help me out?

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int v = 1;
        int x = 2;
        String y = "dog";
        String z = "cat";
        Object[] a = {v, x, y, z};
        printReverse(a, a.length);
    }
    public static void printReverse(Object[] arr, int i) {
        if (i > 0) {
            System.out.println(arr[i]);
            printReverse(arr, i - 1);
        }
        else {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial call to `printReverse` needs to pass `a.length -1`. You’re going out of bounds on the initial call before it ever recurses since arrays are 0-indexed

Comment: Ah you're right thank you very much I just happened to glace over that.

Answer (score 0):

The error message means you are accessing array element 4 but there are only elements with index 0 to 3. Array indices in Java start at 0.